# Можно ли считать одним словом "ГАЗ-3110"?

Tags: словообразование, недопустимая-метка

Аббревиатура считается одним словом, слова, которые пишутся через дефис тоже. Но в данном случае есть ещё и числительное.
Как вы считаете, есть ли случаи, когда "ГАЗ-3110" могло бы считаться одним словом?

Comment: По моему мнению, в предложении "Ту-104 - самый лучший самолёт." подлежащим является слово "Ту-104".

Answer (score 4):

Если признать одним словом ВАЗ-2102, то надо признать словами и все другие (ВАЗ - 1001,1002,1003 и т.д.) Эти словообразования отличаются лексическим значением? Нет. В словаре эти слова зафиксированы? Нет. Более того, от слова ВАЗ к цифровой части можем задать вопрос. НА мой взгляд, это два слова, второе - приложение, но записанное цифрами. Это мои рассуждения. Может, кто-нибудь подтвердит или опровергнет ссылкой на официальный источник.

Answer (score 1):

А в какой связи вообще вопрос возник?
По мне так, если очень хочется, то считайте. Вопрос - зачем. Если считать "словом" то, что отеделяется с обеих сторон пробелами, то да. Но это не всегда так. Наречия, например, в раздельном даже написании, с грамматических позиций логично считать одним словом. 
где ещё может понадобится само понятие одного слова? ну может быть частью речи (существительное, безусловно), членом предложения (подлежащим или дополнением), но для этого опять-таки не надо быть "одним словом". Короче, сам по себе вопросне слишком атуален.